# Process that I attach to debug disappears

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, debugging

I am trying trying to attach to a process in Visual Studio, and I can't find that process that I usually attach to during debugging.

What is going on with Visual Studio?

Comment: @homestead - please use the "visual-studio" tag, not "vs.net"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By virtue of this question being tagged as asp.net I assume you are trying to attach to IIS's w3wp.com process? This process is being recycled once in a while and to restart it you need to  browse to a local page before you can attach your project to it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure to check "Show processes from all users" and "Show processes in all sessions" at the bottom of the Attach to Process dialog?